# Proof that index of Jordan curve in the interior is $\pm 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

These [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697826/winding-number-of-a-simple-closed-curve-in-a-plane) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786984/index-of-a-jordan-curve) have more or less asked the same thing, but to one no answer is given and to the other one reference to a differential topology book is given and one very sketchy proof is presented. So I'm forced to ask the question again: can someone provide a complex-analytic proof that the index of Jordan curve is $\pm 1$ on the interior of the curve, with index defined in the standard, complex analysis way as a certain integral? A reference to a complex analysis text would suffice, or just the presentation of such a proof. Of course one may, in fact is almost certainly forced to, assume the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: I believe that a proof can be had using [Caratheodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)), since we can take use the homeomorphism to show that the boundary is homotopic to a circular contour about the point we are considering. Is there a more elementary proof?

Comment: There are alternatives to using that extension theorem to obtain the required homotopy. You can also get the homotopy from the classification of surfaces, which let's you conclude that the subsurface of the plane bounded by your given Jordan curve and the circular contour is an annulus that is disjoint from the point on which the contour is centered.